# Ruby: Pass options to method only if nonempty

Tags: ruby

I'm given a hash `self.options` (possibly empty), and a method name.  Now I need to call the method, passing in the options hash, like so:

```
obj.send(method_name, ...args..., self.options)
```

But I'd like to support calling methods that don't expect an options hash at all.  So if no options are given (`self.options.empty?`), I'd like to *not* pass an empty hash into the method.  The best I could come up with is this:

```
obj.send(method_name, ...args..., *(self.options.empty? ? [] : [self.options]))
```

Is there a better idiom for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need [] in case options is empty. *nil returns vacuity in that position.

Will this work?

```
obj.send(method_name, ...args..., *([self.options] unless self.options.empty?))
```

by the way, you can omit self, so you can have

```
obj.send(method_name, ...args..., *([options] unless options.empty?))
```

Comment: Very nice, that looks much better!  As a heads-up to everyone, this will only work on Ruby 1.9 -- on 1.8, it will pass `nil` as the last argument if you give `*nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.send(method_name, ...args..., *([self.options.presence].compact))
```

or, how @sawa mentioned right, you can throw away `self`

```
obj.send(method_name, ...args..., *([options.presence].compact))
```

Comment: I think you should go back to your version with [] around self.options.presence. Without [], the hash will be converted to an array. E.g., [1, 2, *{3 => 4}] # => [1, 2, [3, 4]].

Comment: thanx, I din't understand presence of `[]`, now I do. But my solution won't work with [].

Comment: that's better :) but little hacky

Comment: Interesting.  For everyone's reference, #presence is a Rails method, [documented here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence).

Comment: yep. as far as it is part of rails it won't work with ruby unless you'll include it

Comment: [@fl00r, sorry, meant to upvote, but SO won't let me. :(  Thanks for your answer!]